# How to listen to Skaffold events without compiling the Event API protos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, skaffold

I am experimenting with the Skaffold Event API. From a python application I would like to listen to the events over HTTP that are exposed through port 50052 on the [/v1/events](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/blob/d88680e9ede62da65500702670ef72fc9272a06f/pkg/skaffold/event/proto/skaffold.proto#L83-L87) endpoint.

I have compiled the .proto files to python by roughly following [this gRPC guide](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html) and I can listen to the events by connecting to the gRPC server on 50051 using the generated code.

I have tried the python library [hyper](https://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to listen push events through an HTTP2 connection with no luck.

I would like to avoid the overhead of generating code. Is it possible to listen to the Events API through other means?

Answer (score 0):

as per documentation:

> Events are API objects and are removed from the apiserver on master one hour after the last occurrence to avoid filling up the master disk.
>   To provide longer history and aggregation capabilities, a **third party solution** should be installed to capture events.

If that suits your requirements you can try and deploy event exporter to the [stack driver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/events-stackdriver/)

> Stack driver provides information about the incidents and other events associated with alerting policies. you can find more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/).

It support also different client library like C#, GO, Java, python ...

In addition:

> Please be warned: **hyper** is in a very early alpha. You will encounter bugs when using it. In addition, there are very many rough edges. With that said, please try it out in your applications: I need your feedback to fix the bugs and file down the rough edges.

Hope this help.